# AMP URL API not returning valid AMP page

Tags: amp-html, google-apis-explorer

The AMP URL API is not returning an AMP URL despite having a live valid AMP page. The AMP page has been live for 1+ months and serves to Google Search.

Canonical URL: https://www.zales.com/rings

AMP URL: https://www.zales.com/amp/rings

**Example**

Request:

```
https://content-acceleratedmobilepageurl.googleapis.com/v1/ampUrls:batchGet?alt=json&key=API_KEY
```

Request payload:

```
{"urls":["https://www.zales.com/rings"]}
```

Response:

```
{
  "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "https://www.zales.com/rings"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any issue with how you're calling the API at all, according to their [documentation this should work correctly](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/reference/acceleratedmobilepageurl/rest/). I've even tried running the ampbyexample.com site through the validator, and several of my own AMP pages, and all return the same error, with and without a lookup strategy.

```
{
  "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "https://ampbyexample.com/"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another sample:

```
{
  "urls": [
    "https://jamesiv.es/python/2017/07/18/discord-wow-bot"
  ],
  "lookupStrategy": "FETCH_LIVE_DOC"
}
```

With the same error despite there being a valid document:

```
{
  "urlErrors": [
    {
      "errorCode": "NO_AMP_URL",
      "errorMessage": "No AMP URL for the request URL.",
      "originalUrl": "https://jamesiv.es/python/2017/07/18/discord-wow-bot"
    }
  ]
}
```

It might be worth posting a bug report for this on [Github](https://github.com/ampproject) incase someone from Google's AMP team doesn't see this.